# Cannot enumerate sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph Dot Net package, Im unable to call:

```
await client.Sites.Request().GetAsync();
```

Even though on the graph explorer I can hit the sites endpoint fine:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sites` is a collection, and can be passed an identifier to get a single `site` resource. In your case, you are fetching child sites of the `root` site.

In the REST API, this is represented as `~/v1.0/sites/root/sites`.

In the .NET SDK, you will write this as:

`var sites = graphClient.Sites["Root"].Sites.Request().GetAsync();`

Hope this helps.